# modal in nextjs13 13.4

Tags: redux-toolkit, web-frontend, next.js13

I wanted to create a Modal in NextJS 13.4 (with the new layout.tsx file system). Im also using redux so the confusion arises. what would be in my layout file. Im attaching a ss of my layout file without modal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00kez.png)

I read the documentation but it was unclear how to wrap both the children and the modal in the providers tag